# How to sum values at index[2] with same values of index[0] in python list of tuple

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How to sum values at index[2] with same values of index[0] in python list of tuple?

```
rows = [(1,'abc', 101),(2, 'rt',8765),(5, 'dfdf', 321),(1, 'abc', 477),(1, 'abc', 233),(3, 'rree', 323), (5, 'dfdf', 4531), (1, 'abc', 99)]
ids = 1,2,5,3
```

at index 0 is , how to sum of values at `index[2] (101, 477, 99)` of 1 and `(4531, 321)` of 5 have similar ids

Comment: Unclear what you're asking, provide some input and output test cases examples and your coding attempt

Comment: Still unclear. Please provide the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to aggregate the values at index 2 according to the id at index 0. You can use a dictionary to sum up your data:

```
rows = [
    (1,'abc', 101),(2, 'rt',8765),(5, 'dfdf', 321),(1, 'abc', 477),
    (1, 'abc', 233),(3, 'rree', 323), (5, 'dfdf', 4531), (1, 'abc', 99)]
aggregated = {}
for row in rows:
    aggregated[row[0]] = aggregated.get(row[0], 0) + row[2]
```

Now `aggregated` is `{1: 910, 2: 8765, 3: 323, 5: 4852}`.

Or - if you don't want this annoying `get` method - you can use the power of [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
aggregated = defaultdict(int)
for row in rows:
    aggregated[row[0]] += row[2]
```

Now `aggregated` is `defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {1: 910, 2: 8765, 3: 323, 5: 4852})`.